# Is it good practice to "return warn" in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to check for a condition, print a warning, and return from a subroutine with a single line of code. This works (and I think warn returns 1):

```
return warn "can't find file" if not -f $input_file;
```

Can I do this safely? Or is there a better way to go?

Comment: Why would you want to continue execution if the input file isn't found?

Comment: Because in my [large] script it makes sense for this function not to process an input file without terminating the whole script.

Comment: Your goal of *a single line of code* seems arbitrary and bizarre. If *a single line* is a string that has no newlines then the solution is simple. Please describe your constraints

Comment: @Borodin, I think I meant no curly brackets :) I would do something like this in C: `return CHECK_AND_WARN(condition, "warning")`. Just wanted to know if there's something common in Perl as there's always a concise way to do things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's perfectly safe, but it requires looking at the [source](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/89550e55e963f08f03d979563451d5234f74be10:/pp_sys.c#l423) to determine what value is returned (true), and it leaves no readable option to control what value gets returned. This is rather important because you'd normally want to return nothing/undef/false in this situation, but you're currently returning true.

All of the following alternatives allow you to specify the value returned:

```
warn("can't find file"), return if !-f $input_file;

(warn "can't find file"), return if !-f $input_file;

if (!-f $input_file) { warn "can't find file"; return }

-f $input_file or warn("can't find file"), return;

-f $input_file or (warn "can't find file"), return;
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do you use `!` instead of `not`?

Comment: Personal pref, and it makes the alts as short as the orig :)

Comment: not is for flow control; its low precedence makes it error prone to use otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
return 0 * warn "can't find file" if not -f $input_file;
```

Will return 0 so whatever called the subroutine will know it failed.

This would be my lazy version of

```
if (!-f $input_file) { warn "can't find file"; return 0; }
```